# De-referencing void pointer to a pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers

I'm using a threading library given to me at school and having trouble understanding how to pass a reference of an array of pointers to a method, or rather, I'm having trouble de-referencing and using the pointer array.

The situation that I (believe I) understand is this:

```
int main(void)
{
    Foo* bar = new Foo();

    // Passing instance of Foo pointer by reference 
    CThread *myThread = new CThread(MyFunction, ACTIVE, &bar);

    return 0;
}

UINT __stdcall MyFunction(void *arg)
{
    Foo* bar = *(Foo*)(arg); 

    return 0;
}
```

I'm creating a pointer to a Foo object and passing it by reference to a thread running MyFunction, which accepts a void pointer as its argument. MyFunction then casts "arg" to a Foo pointer and de-references it to get the original object.

My problem arises when I want to pass an array of Foo pointers instead of just one:

```
int main(void)
{
    Foo* barGroup[3] = 
    {
        new Foo(),
        new Foo(),
        new Foo()
    };

    // Passing instance of Foo pointer by reference 
    CThread *myThread = new CThread(MyFunction, ACTIVE, &barGroup);

    return 0;
}

UINT __stdcall MyFunction(void *arg)
{
    // This is wrong; how do I do this??
    Foo* barGroup[3] = *(Foo[]*)(arg); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing the `addressof` a pointer?

Comment: You are not passing by reference. You are passing a pointer to a pointer to an object. Also, why are you using `void*`?

Comment: `*(Foo*(*)[3])` But why?

Comment: using void*s like this, and in almost every case, is notoriously bad practice.

Comment: Why are you using `void*` and not the real type?

Comment: "MyFunction which accepts a void pointer as its argument (I'm simplifying my usage of a *threading library*)." Guys, some threading APIs, like say, pthreads, let you pass a `void*` to the thread function as user data. (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html)

Comment: Yes, I'm using a threading library and should have known that I couldn't simplify my example without raising suspision... I've updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `MyFunction(&barGroup);` with `MyFunction(barGroup);` (thus passing a pointer to the first element instead of a pointer to the entire array) and use a nested pointer:

```
Foo** barGroup = (Foo**)(arg);
```

Then you can simply use `barGroup[0]`, `barGroup[1]` and `barGroup[2]`.

Comment: So let's see if I understand; I'm passing a pointer to the first element because arrays in C++ are pointers?

The casting part I don't understand as much. I'm casting to a pointer to a pointer, is that because my original object was an array of pointers, which is actually a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: **Arrays are not pointers**, but they can silently be converted to pointers. If you want to dig deeper, read our [FAQ on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/).

Comment: Thanks, the FAQ looks very helpful!